# Smalltalk tagged questions not automatically syntax-highlighted

Tags: feature-request, syntax-highlighting

Based on [Changes to syntax highlighting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72082/changes-to-syntax-highlighting) meta post I believe the following changes would switch on automatic colour syntax highlighting for Smalltalk (and related) tagged questions:

```
[smalltalk] = lang-smalltalk
[pharo] = lang-smalltalk
[squeak] = lang-smalltalk
```

Also, if it's possible to change, Smalltalk `"comments"` (text between double quotes) are coloured as a string (text between single quotes) and not being highlighted like a normal language comment annotation.

For reference, here's an example of a [Smalltalk answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47486747/12195) where I've forced the syntax highlighting and same code on a [Github gist](https://gist.github.com/draegtun/5093f97c63b26ef533705edf61a78dc0)

Comment: There is no `lang-smalltalk` in the prettifier. You see the result of `lang-default` instead. There is no smalltalk support because apparently the commenting conventions used in the language can't be supported by the lexer used.

Comment: Thanks @MartijnPieters - I didn't check before but GCP doesn't have `lang-smalltalk` :(   I've had enough trouble getting `lang-rebol` into GCP so don't want to go down that route again!!   So Smalltalk tags using `lang-default` might be a good compromise for now?

Comment: That's what you get when you use `lang-smalltalk` anyway.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - At this moment Smalltalk tagged questions/answers  aren't automatically syntax highlighted so it isn't using (or falling through to) `lang-default`

Comment: I've set these three tags to use 'default' now. There are more *-smalltalk tags, should those have the same setting?

Comment: Thanks @MartijnPieters  re: *-smalltalk. - definitely `gnu-smalltalk` & `amber-smalltalk`.  Not sure what others are but probably yes to them to.

Comment: `dolphin-smalltalk`. You can search for tags on the tags page. :-) Done!

Comment: @MartijnPieters - I tried that but it didn't work for me ;-P    I found those two tags under [Related Tags](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/smalltalk/info).   Yes `dolphin-smalltalk` can be added.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - After sleeping on it I think all these changes should be rolled-back to NONE.  There's too many edge cases for Smalltalk so you would only get complaints and more requests on Smalltalk highlighting not working correctly.  Correct solution is to get `lang-smalltalk` grammar added to GCP.  Interim solution is just to use `<!-- language: lang-smalltalk -->` on specific code where it works OK.  Many thanks for you time.

Comment: Check, I've rolled back the changes.